# how to use NS_ENUM

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I want to use NS_ENUM. I have written the below code in my .m file. Now when my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called . I got the index path. Now corresponding to that index path I want to extract the string associated with it. For example for index path 0 I want to extract images.

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, TABLE_SECTION_ITEMS)
{

    Images = 0,
    Videos = 1,
    Documents = 2,    
    Audios = 3

};
```

Answer (score 0):

What we usually do in this case is to always keep the last item in enum as "count" or "last". In your case for instance:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, TABLE_SECTION_ITEMS)
{
    TABLE_SECTION_Images,
    TABLE_SECTION_Videos,
    TABLE_SECTION_Documents,
    TABLE_SECTION_Audios,

    TABLE_SECTION_Count
};
```

We do not specify values as that may break logic. But you can reorder items and you can deprecate them by putting items after "count".

The usage of it then looks something like this:

```
@interface ViewController()<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (NSString *)tableSectionName:(TABLE_SECTION_ITEMS)item {
    switch (item) {
        case TABLE_SECTION_Images: return @"Images";
        case TABLE_SECTION_Videos: return @"Videos";
        case TABLE_SECTION_Documents: return @"Documents";
        case TABLE_SECTION_Audios: return @"Audios";
        case TABLE_SECTION_Count: return nil;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return TABLE_SECTION_Count;
}

- (nonnull UITableViewCell *)tableView:(nonnull UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(nonnull NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = [self tableSectionName:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

@end
```

So the row count is simply `TABLE_SECTION_Count` and you can naturally convert between `NSInteger` and your enum as seen in `[self tableSectionName:indexPath.row]`.

Naturally a mapping for strings still needs to be done as in `tableSectionName`. It is not idle but it is now more then manageable;

When you add a new enumeration value (let's say `TABLE_SECTION_Documents2`) you will get n error in `tableSectionName` that you need to add a new case (Or rather an error associated to it that says Control may reach end of non-void function). So as developer you are forced to fill it like:

```
- (NSString *)tableSectionName:(TABLE_SECTION_ITEMS)item {
    switch (item) {
        case TABLE_SECTION_Images: return @"Images";
        case TABLE_SECTION_Videos: return @"Videos";
        case TABLE_SECTION_Documents: return @"Documents";
        case TABLE_SECTION_Documents2: return @"Documents";
        case TABLE_SECTION_Audios: return @"Audios";
        case TABLE_SECTION_Count: return nil;
    }
}
```

Another bonus here is that we can have "Documents" twice.
And to deprecate an item all we need to do is move the enum after the count:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, TABLE_SECTION_ITEMS)
{
    TABLE_SECTION_Images,
    TABLE_SECTION_Videos,
    TABLE_SECTION_Documents2,
    TABLE_SECTION_Audios,

    TABLE_SECTION_Count, // Always keep last

    // Deprecated items
    TABLE_SECTION_Documents
};
```

Now the old "Documents" will not be listed in your table view without a need to change any of your code. Not ideal but still pretty neat.